# Node: Is it bad to use a non-LTS version of node in production?

Tags: node.js

I've been using a non-LTS (11) version of Node in production for a while.  I was told this is not the best practice.  I haven't encountered any problems but should I upgrade to the closest LTS version, 12, or does it not really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should. When the support of your non-LTS version is over, then you are on your own with all the security issues and bugs. Usually, the upgrade of the node version is quite painless. What stops you from using a newer version?

Comment: thanks, that's what i figured.  Is it painless?  I assume after I install the LTS locally, I just have to 1) remove my node modules and `npm install` and then 2) overwrite my existing `package-lock.json` since it will be different now and commit that.  Am I missing anything else?

Comment: You can use nvm or n for Node version management.